# Why my project is generating jar file 32 bit if my system is 64 bit?

Tags: java, build, ant, compilation

I have a little issue here. I'm generating `jar` files using ANT, in my system when I type in CMD java -version, I receive this message:

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

But when I generate my `jar` file, it's generating in 32 bits. I don't know why is generating a file in 32 bits, because I have installed in my system java 64 bits.

I want to fix this, because when I use a `jar` file 32 bits in a system using 64 bits, I have a limitation about JVM memory, and I need more memory to make somethings work good.

I'm using this [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sVsu8TECQWC6mp_KPjm-TJUfGlGMBoSx/view?usp=sharing)

It's a project repository open source from [here](https://github.com/G-Robson26/aion-lightning-2.7)

But in google drive file, have a folder with ANT to build the project. So I'm using ANT, what I'm doing to test is this:

Opening folder `trunk/AL-game/build_gameserver.bat` and then, when I open my task manager I see java binary file using 32 bits in the process.

I tried a lot of things, but nothings happen, still building in 32 bits, but my system is 64 bits, doesn't sense for me.

Comment: Jar files are just zip files that contained your class files, which the JVM should not care if they were created in 32 or 64-bit arch. That's what whole point of the VM. So, it is not very clear exactly what you mean when you say that your jar file is 32-bit. How did you determine that?

Comment: You cant build a jar in 32bit or 64bit. You build a jar. Thats it. If you see that your application is exeuted in 32bit, thats because youre using a 32bit JVM to run it

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo  Look at this: https://ibb.co/p1cVNDB

Comment: I don't knew the architecture of java generate a jar file without architecture... Then this jar file is interpreted on the machine being executed? That is, does this mean that my machine is using a 32-bit jvm? @codeflush.dev

Comment: Ok, you're right.. I open my task manager and I see my directory from java.exe was using a old java 32 bits! 
Thanks guys!!!